# Sum of sequence complexity

Tags: time-complexity

I try to find out what is the time complexity of this program:

```
for (int i =0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
         //Do something O(1)
    }
}
```

I tried to find any explanation, As I see, it something like Arithmetic progression sum `(n(n-1)/2)`.

Is it? or it's just `O(n^2)`

Comment: Since $n$ is constant, your program runs in $O(1)$.

Comment: I meant n is unknown. if it's just n? (I update the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop will iterate once with $j=i+1$, once again with $j=i+2$, and so on, up to the last iteration with $j=n-1$, so there will be, for each $i$ in the outer loop, $(i+1)-(n-1)-1=n+i-1$ time contributions from the inner loop. Add these to get your answer.

Comment: So you mean the complexity is n^2?

Comment: @motis10 Kinda. In fact, you can show that if the "//Do something O(1)" is interpreted as "1" then the complexity is $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Im not sure I understand you. So the answer is n^2 or nlogn?

Comment: @motis10 Let's see: the actual complexity is $n(n-1)/2$ that is $\frac{1}{2}n^2-\frac{1}{2}n$. Is that $O(n^2)$ or $O(n\log n)$?